# TypeError: Feature names are only supported if all input features have string names, but your input has ['str', 'str_'] as column name types

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

When I try to fit the scikit-learn's StandardScaler into my pandas dataframe I get the following error:

> TypeError: Feature names are only supported if all input features have
> string names, but your input has ['str', 'str_'] as feature name /
> column name types. If you want feature names to be stored and
> validated, you must convert them all to strings, by using X.columns =
> X.columns.astype(str) for example. Otherwise you can remove feature /
> column names from your input data, or convert them all to a non-string
> data type.

This error occurs in this part of my code:

```
scaler.fit(data[map_keys])
```

Here data is a dataframe and `map_keys` is a list containing only string values. Here is a sample from the data:

`>>  data[map_keys].head()` outputs:

```
         loss  revenue  visit_number  ... 
1964      1.0      0.0           1.0  ...
1402      2.0      0.0           1.0  ...
2539      2.0      0.0           1.0  ...
86        2.0      0.0           1.0  ...
808       2.0      0.0           2.0  ...
```

What I did to fix this issue was to convert all elements in `map_keys` into `str` type with:

```
map_keys = [str(k) for k in map_keys]
```

as some of the elements in the list were of type `np.str_` when I first encountered the issue. But the error still persists...
Note that the scikit-learn version I use in this code is `1.2.1`.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data before transformation and the code before the standard scaler, please?

Comment: Added in the question body.

Answer (score 4):

For me the astype(str) solution wasn't working so I get aroung with:

```
    X= X.rename(str,axis="columns")
```

Comment: It's 4.30 am and you just saved my life - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I renamed the columns using the one-liner included in the error message:

```
X.columns = X.columns.astype(str)
```

and it worked.